# How to control a direction of a one way road when upgrading from two way road?

Tags: cities-skylines

I have a two way road which I want to upgrade to a one way road, how can I choose the direction?

This is a specific question about change the direction of already exiting one way road.

Comment: The original question doesn't contain an answer which I found by experimenting with the game: select a one way road, choose 'upgrade' shape type and click on a segment. If you don't like the direction chosen by game just right-mouse-click on a segment again and the direction will be changed!